# React native 0.57.8 but React native navigation Version is : 1.1.471 but current version for React native navigation is : 2.20.2

Tags: node.js, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using the React native 0.57.8 but React native navigation Version is: 1.1.471 
but the current version for React native navigation is: 2.20.2

May I know which version for React native navigation I have to install for upgrade My Application already on live but I want to upgrade the React native navigation not sure which version I have to use.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

That's not a coding question though, but whatever I am explaining will be applicable for all the updations of libraries anyone wants to do.

> Just go through with the Release notes, check with the new
>   functionalities added or older functionalities deprecated. After
>   updating, a thorough check of your app will be required to check with
>   the flows. Create a separate branch and work over that, if all works
>   fine, merge it with your primary branch and push the app for update